# Problem with getID() in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

here is my code.. when i am using `getData()` , it will give whole array..

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('warranty/warranty');

                    $war = $model->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',  array('eq' => $productId))
                                    ->load();

echo'<pre>';print_r($war->getData()); die;
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [product_id] => 554
            [warranty_period] => 2 month
            [price_in_warranty] => 500
            [price_out_warranty] => 24
        )

)
```

but when i try to get id using

```
echo $war->getId(); die;
```

nothing will display. **how to get id through above array**?

Comment: you can not call get id on collection object

Comment: if you have only one record in collection try as $war->getFirstItem()->getId()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're dealing with a collection, you can't simply call:

```
$war->getId();
```

If you want the id of the first item of your collection you can call:

```
$war->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

If you want to get the ids of every items in your collection you can do:

```
foreach ($war as $item)
{
    echo $item->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really wanted is this:

```
$war[0]->getId();
```

Because from your var dump, you can see that `$war` is a collection.

Of course, you can iterate through `$war` if you have multiple items in it.